# Export 'unstable_act' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react'

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I developed an application with react-three-gui and @react-three/drei. After experimenting with the package.json, I was given the following error:

Error in question after changing the package.json file

[image: Error in question after changing the package.json file]

But despite everything, even after undoing my changes, the error remains.

Things I have tried:

- deleting node modules and reinstalling (no changes)
- undoing changes and going to previous commits (error remained even then)
- deleting only react-three-fiber (react-three-gui throws an error)

I have spent days looking for a solution but can't find one that relates to this specific problem. Anything helps.

package.json

[image: Picture of package.json]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was able to solve the problem by just creating a new react project, and transferring the code and 3d models I created to the new project. Once I reinstalled the necessary packages into the new project, everything started working again perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the dependencies.

First of all there's both `react-three-fiber` and `@react-three/fiber`. The former dependency is deprecated, but it has a dependency on `@react-three/fiber` and version `latest`.

So, this leads to a dependency on the latest version of  `@react-three/fiber` which in turn has a dependency on `"react": "^18.0.0"`, despite the `"react": "^17.0.2"` set in your project's package.json.

So, make sure you get rid of the deprecated dependency and align the dependencies so there are no version conflicts.

Reference for a similar issue: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/2037